# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined when deleting a firebase object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

i get the following error when deleting a firebase object

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at ScheduleService.push../src/app/schedule.service.ts.ScheduleService.deleteSchedule
>   (schedule.service.ts:37)

I check the objects to ensure an id existed on the property.

> { "appointment_date": { "seconds": 1544677200, "nanoseconds": 0 },
>   "appointment_hour": "01:00 pm", "id": "JKD3spgb8qtMX97XhjLG", "name":
>   "Barnny" }

I ultimately want to delete an object from the firebase collection.

**schedule.service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Schedule } from './models/schedule.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { AngularFirestore,AngularFirestoreDocument, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ScheduleService {
  formData: Schedule;
  schedules: Observable<Schedule[]>;
  scheduleList: AngularFirestoreDocument<Schedule>;
  scheduleCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Schedule>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.scheduleCollection = this.firestore.collection('schedules');

    this.schedules = this.scheduleCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(changes =>{
      return changes.map(a =>{
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Schedule;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      });
    }));

  }

  // ignore that code it doesnt work lol


  getAppointments(){
    return this.schedules;
  }

  deleteSchedule(schedule: Schedule) {
    this.scheduleList = this.firestore.doc(`schedules/${schedule.id}`);
    this.scheduleList.delete();
  }
```

**schedule-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { ScheduleService } from '../schedule.service';
import { Schedule } from '../models/schedule.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-schedule-list',
  templateUrl: './schedule-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./schedule-list.component.css']
})
export class ScheduleListComponent implements OnInit {
  list:Schedule[];
  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore, private service: ScheduleService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAppointments().subscribe(schedules => {
      //console.log(list);
      this.list = schedules;
    });
  }

  deleteSchedule(event, schedule) {
    const response = confirm('are you sure you want to delete?');
    if (response ) {
      this.service.deleteSchedule(schedule);
    }
    return;
  }
```

**Model.ts**

```
export class Schedule {
    id:string;
    name:string;
    appointment_date:string;
    appointment_hour: string;

}
```

**schedule-list.component.html**

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="row">
      <div *ngFor="let appoint of list" class="col-md-8 myCenter mt-2"> 
        <!-- the bottom code should work if items within list exist. -->
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
              Name: {{appoint.name}}
              <a href="#" class="secondary-content float-right">
                <i (click)="deleteSchedule($event, schedule)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
              </a>

          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <span><small>Appointment Set:</small></span><p>{{ appoint.appointment_date.toDate() | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</p>
            <span><small>Time:</small></span><p>{{ appoint.appointment_hour }}</p>
            <span> {{ appoint | json }}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that your error message *doesn't* say that id is undefined - it suggests that schedule is undefined in this context.

Comment: the id is equal to null on the firebase database backend, what could this mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read everything correct.

You loop this: `*ngFor="let appoint of list"`.

And then send schedule.
`<i (click)="deleteSchedule($event, schedule)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>`

Should be:

`<i (click)="deleteSchedule($event, appoint)" class="fa fa-trash"></i>`